# Why should we use a friend function to define the comparison operator?

Tags: c++, friend-function

From http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/142-function-template-instances/

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;
public:
    Cents(int nCents)
        : m_nCents(nCents)
    {
    }

    friend bool operator>(Cents &c1, Cents&c2)  // <--- why friend?
    {
        return (c1.m_nCents > c2.m_nCents) ? true: false;
    }
};
```

We could have also implemented it like this:

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;
public:
    Cents(int nCents)
        : m_nCents(nCents)
    {
    }

    bool operator> (Cents& c2)  // <---
    {
        return (this->m_nCents > c2.m_nCents) ? true: false;
    }
};
```

Is there any downside of using the second implementation?

Comment: Don't forget const correctness.

Comment: Explained well in the [C++-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421729/14065)

Comment: If you must use `? true : false` on boolean expressions, then remember that the result is also a boolean expression, so you should write `((c1.m_nCents > c2.m_nCents) ? true : false) ? true : false)`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe you mean `(((c1.m_nCents > c2.m_nCents) ? true : false) ? true : false) ? false == false : true != true`. Don't want those boolean expressions getting away from you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using const references as the parameters, the first implementation can be used in conditions like this: `bool b = 42 > c;` which will provide a compiler error in the second implementation. This will automatically creates a `Cent` object using the integer `42` (since constructor is not defined as `explicit`) and then use the `friend` function for comparison. See point 7 in this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.9)

Answer (score 0):

The first is defined as Class Member overload operator , the second is a Nonmember overload operator .When Nonmember function accesses the private member
`private:
    int m_nCents;`,  `friend` should be added.Even I change to `public:int m_nCents;`,it does not work.`friend` seems to be a rule, not because of member access limitation. But you can move the Nonmember operator out of class body and access public member variable. Any better idea?I feel confused. I think that **ALL** Nonmember operator(have same parameter number with operand and can not be called as a member function ) must be declared as `friend` in class body.

`>` is a binary operator which have two parameter for each operand. You have found that the Class Member overload operator `>` only have **one** explicit parameter and an implicit `this` parameter. Nonmember operator must have two.

```
class Cents{
  private:
     int m_nCents;
  public:
  Cents(int nCents)
     : m_nCents(nCents)
   {
   }

   friend bool operator>(Cents &c1, Cents&c2); //Nomember 

   bool operator<(Cents &c1); //class member
};

bool operator>(Cents &c1, Cents&c2)  // <--- why friend?
{
   //cout << "in >"  << endl;
   return (c1.m_nCents > c2.m_nCents) ? true: false;
}

bool Cents::operator<(Cents &c1)
{
    //cout << "in <"  << endl;
    return (this->m_nCents < c1.m_nCents) ? true: false;
}

int main(){
 //nomember
 //if(poor.operator>(rich))  //compiler error 
 if(poor > rich){
     cout << "oh yeal!" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "oh no!" << endl;
 }

 //member
 //if(poor.operator<(rich)) //can call this way
 if(poor.operator<(rich)){
     cout << "oh yeal!" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "oh no!" << endl;
 }

}
```

I move implementations out of class body. Now you can see class member operator has a `Cents::` qualifier just like member function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see much difference in most of the practical examples *in general*.

I prefer the 2nd option, which gets associated with the `class` directly. Moreover, following syntax is more appropriate:

```
bool operator> (const Cents& c2) const
{         //    ^^^^^            ^^^^^
  return (this->m_nCents > c2.m_nCents); // simple
}
```

Comment: The difference is that a non-member allows type conversions on both arguments, while a member only allows them on the second.

Answer (score -2):

There's no reason to tag a public method with friend. Friend functions are useful for unrelated classes accessing private or protected members.

That said, you could just drop friend from the first implementation and it'll work fine.

Comment: Its tagged friend because it is a free function not a public method.

Comment: If you drop friend, you have a compiler error, cause you cannot change an operator arity (the number of arguments it takes) when you overload it.